# Parsing with prolog

Tags: parsing, prolog, swi-prolog

I am trying to parse with prolog:

I need to run a code which recieves a text in the command and parse it depending of the input.

Command **cal** returns **calendar(Month, Year)** where month ∈ [1-12] and year ∈ [1-9999]. If there is no month given, it returns the year, if both are not specified return current month and year.
Example.

Option1

```
?- read_sentence(X).
|: cal 1 2000
X = calendar(1,2000).
```

Option2

```
?- read_sentence(X).
|: cal  2000
X = calendar(2000).`
```

Option3

```
?- read_sentence(X).
|: cal
X = calendar(1,2016).
```

So far I am able to read the sentence, and print it, but I have no idea how to parse or even where to begin.

```
read_sentence(X) :- get0(C),
   read_sentence(X, L,C),
   name(X, L).
read_sentence(_, [], X) :-
   member(X, `.\n\t`), !.
read_sentence(X, [C|L], C) :-
   get0(C1),
   read_sentence(X, L, C1).
```

Which does:

```
?- read_sentence(X).
|: Hello  there
X = 'Hello  there'.
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by *parse*?  The thing to be parsed appears to be what you get from `read_sentence`; what should be the result of parsing?

Comment: I mean if I enter read_sentence(X). This will open a command line where an input is required.

Input: `cal 1 200`

The code has to recognize that it has "cal" "number between 1-12" and "number between 1 and 9999"

Output: `calendar(1,200)`

Comment: Which means you need a way to break down the input string into a list of individual words, correct?

Answer (score 1):

SWI-Prolog has a predicate, `split_string`, for splitting up strings into "words", which might be what you need for this rather simple parsing, which you could then use to decide how to invoke `calendar`.